# Passing every combination of two arrays into url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

What I need to do is pass every combination of 2 arrays with different lengths into an axios call.  I'm assuming I need do something like a nested for loop to get all the iterations, but I'm not sure how to pass those in the URL.

```js
const searchArr = [
  "Search 1",
  "Search 2",
  "Search 3",
  "Search 4",
  "Search 5",
  "Search 6",
];

const locationArr = [
  "80829",
  "32628",
  "76112",
  "28273",
  "93727",
  "30331",
  "90067",
  "95814",
  "94601",
  "20036",
  "60637",
  "02461",
  "10452",
  "78701",
];

const search = searchArr[0]
const location = locationArr[0]

let url = `http://localhost:3000/search?search=${search}&location=${location}`;

function getList() {
  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then((res) => {
      setTableData(res.data.jobs);
    })

    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
const searchArr = [
  "Search 1",
  "Search 2",
  "Search 3",
  "Search 4",
  "Search 5",
  "Search 6",
];

const locationArr = [
  "80829",
  "32628",
  "76112",
  "28273",
  "93727",
  "30331",
  "90067",
  "95814",
  "94601",
  "20036",
  "60637",
  "02461",
  "10452",
  "78701",
];

function callEveryCombination(){
   searchArr.forEach(search => {
       locationArr.forEach(location => {
           getList(search, location);
       });
   });
}

function getList(search, location) {
  const url = `http://localhost:3000/search?search=${search}&location=${location}`;

  return axios
    .get(url)
    .then((res) => {
      setTableData(res.data.jobs);
    })

    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: try having `getList` before `callEveryCombination`, to make the code both clean, and making the function be able to use callEveryCombination as soon as it is created.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a nested loop (forEach):

```
for (const item of searchArr) {
    for (const location of locationArr) {
    // here put the code
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer the `forEach`:

```
searchArr.forEach(item => {
    locationArr.forEach(location => {
    // here send the request
    }
});
```